# How many seconds is 100 Ticks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a command with a Wither Boss in it and I am making an Invulnerability time and I put it to 100 ticks. Can someone PLEASE help me?

Comment: nice thx, i forgot this and there we go ty!

Comment: Hello @kidwholikescodes! Welcome to Arqade! Please keep interactions that would comment on the post as a comment, and only use the answer functionality for... well,  answers. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 5):

There are 20 ticks per second, so 100 would be 5 seconds.  This is why a 20Hz clock is the fastest redstone clock you can have in Minecraft.